# Apple Mach-O Linker Error xCode 6.3 ios 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I get a error message when trying to run my ios app ande Xcode 6.3 returns Apple Mach-O Linker Error. What's the problem?

I just compiled a project and Xcode 5 returns "Apple Mach-O-Linker error". How do I fix them? How to solve the problem? I am using iOS 7.

Here is the whole error:

```
Ld /Users/eric/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AskingApp-ajdanpgjvvbbvuatgxrdrnwjrunp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AskingApp.app/AskingApp normal x86_64
cd "/Users/eric/Downloads/AskingApp20150421 2"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk -L/Users/eric/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AskingApp-ajdanpgjvvbbvuatgxrdrnwjrunp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/eric/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AskingApp-ajdanpgjvvbbvuatgxrdrnwjrunp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/eric/Downloads/AskingApp20150421\ 2/AskingApp -filelist /Users/eric/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AskingApp-ajdanpgjvvbbvuatgxrdrnwjrunp/Build/Intermediates/AskingApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AskingApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AskingApp.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework Security -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -lz -framework CFNetwork -framework Parse -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/eric/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AskingApp-ajdanpgjvvbbvuatgxrdrnwjrunp/Build/Intermediates/AskingApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AskingApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AskingApp_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/eric/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AskingApp-ajdanpgjvvbbvuatgxrdrnwjrunp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AskingApp.app/AskingApp

ld: truncated fat file. Slice from 24061796 to 30544388 is past end of file with length 30544327 file '/Users/eric/Downloads/AskingApp20150421 2/AskingApp/Parse.framework/Parse' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anyone?

Comment: quick guess, your parse sdk framework is not correctly added or doesn't support 64bit.

Comment: Thanks! How do I fix that? @NicolasS

Comment: @Erfra you need to add your framework to Link Binary ( YourProject.xcodeproj -> BuildPhases -> LinkBinary ) or you need to compile your framework to architecture 64. ( Build Settings ->  Architecture, check everything to include arm64 )